# Starting this morning my mouse stops working as soon as I start any application

Tags: usb, mouse, touchpad

I am using a logitech M325 mouse, the one with a dongle that plugs into a usb port, all was well last night but this morning as soon as I start any application the mouse justs stops working, I've tired a new mouse as well as a wired mouse the just plugs into a usb port with the same result.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 on an Acer Aspire 5 laptop and have never had any issue before.
I tired plugging an mp3 player into the usb port after the mouse stops working and it seems to work fine.
I'd really appreciate any advice. The touch pad works fine but I hate using it.

Comment: Well, I ran xinput and didn't see my mouse listed. Rebooted and xinput showed the mouse. For some reason it continued to work this time. This isn't an answer because I have no idea why but for now it's working.

Comment: Just an update, this is a dual boot laptop, I booted to windows which I very rarely do and all three usb ports worked in windows. When I booted back to Linux they were all still working and still are?????

Comment: OK, it looks like I've narrowed it down to 20.04.3:  When I am running: 20.04.3 (linux 5.11.0-46-generic) my usb mouse just stops working randomly, actually the usb ports just seem to stop working.

My laptop is a dual boot so I booted to windows and everything worked fine.

The next thing I did was to boot back to Ubuntu 20.04.2 (linux 5.11.0-44-generic) and everything works here as well.

Has anyone else had any issues like this and perhaps have a fix for it?

Comment: Does [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1956849) help? Some users are reporting issues with 5.11.0-44 and are reverting to a previous kernel.